# Bugzilla 5.0.4 on Centos 6.9 .htaccess: Options not allowed here

Tags: apache, bugzilla

I've just installed Bugzilla 5.0.4 on Centos 6.9 (upgrade from Bugzilla 4.2.1)

It's `checksetup.pl` passes, but the website returns 'Internal Server Error'.
The only thing in apache's error_log is:

> /var/www/html/bugzilla/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

How should I approach fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Add 'Options' to AllowOverride in /etc/httpd/conf.d/buzilla.conf, and restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

"Require" is a type of AuthConfig directives. You need to specify, in httpd.conf, that type of directives are allowed in .htaccess. (
See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/overrides.html#override-indexes)

```
<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    AllowOverride Limit AuthConfig Options Indexes FileInfo
</Directory>
```

The instructions from bugzilla does not have **AuthConfig** and the rest of the line here. You need to add them all in order to make /var/www/html/bugzilla/.htaccess acceptable to apache.